# BrowserSync doesn't work from VPS with Nginx installed on it

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, gulp, browser-sync

I use [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/) on my *Ubuntu 14.04 VPS* as my development environment and right now I'm working on a *Nodejs + Express* application and taking advantage of *gulp* and remote `ssh` terminals.

But, high ports (e.g. 8080, 8081, ...) are blocked in my work place and all I have is port 80 !

So, I've set up *Nginx* to map all my domains with their subdomains to different ports on my *VPS's localhost*. For example `domain1.com` to `http://localhost:8080` or `sub1.domain2.de` to `http://localhost:9090` and so on, to be able to serve different apps on one VPS all through port 80.

Everything is working fine until when I try to setup *BrowserSync* to automate reloads on my PC's browser. Here is the pseudo-config :

Nginx map table : *(Working fine)*

- `ahs502.ir` to `http://localhost:8081`
- `dev.ahs502.ir` to `http://localhost:8082`
- `bs.ahs502.ir` to `http://localhost:8083`
- `test.ahs502.ir` to `http://localhost:8084`

Gulp task for BrowserSync : *(It seems to work fine)*

```
var bs, browserSync = require("browser-sync");
...
gulp.task('bs', ['start-node'], () => {
    bs = browserSync.create();
    bs.init({
        proxy: "localhost:8081", // Address of my running local node server
        port: 8082, // dev. ...
        ui: {
            port: 8083, // bs. ...
            weinre: {
                port: 8084 // test. ...
            }
        }
    });
    bs.watch("app/views/*.jade").on("change", bs.reload);
});
```

Then, I start the Gulp task : *(In my remote terminal over `ssh` on my VPS)*

```
$ gulp bs
```

It starts without errors and I can browse `dev.ahs502.ir` in my PC's browser nicely, BUT, this is where I encounter this periodically repeating error in my browser's console :

```
GET http://dev.ahs502.ir:8082/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LEye85F          browser-sync-client.2.11.2.js:1
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

GET http://dev.ahs502.ir:8082/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LEyeEh8          browser-sync-client.2.11.2.js:1
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

GET http://dev.ahs502.ir:8082/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LEyeLGy          browser-sync-client.2.11.2.js:1
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

...
```

And, automatic reload does not work.

It is simply adding an extra `:8082` at the end of `http://dev.ahs502.ir` *(which will be translated to `http://localhost:8082` at my server by itself)* so the request can't be resolved and become timed out.

I've done whatever I could but I wasn't able to fix it! Any help will be appericated!!

Sorry for the long story. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found a good answer !

I've configured *Nginx* to :

map `dev.ahs502.ir` to `localhost:8082/` and

map `dev.ahs502.ir/browser-sync/socket.io/` to `localhost:8083/browser-sync/socket.io/` like this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.ahs502.ir;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /browser-sync/socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8083/browser-sync/socket.io/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

then, set `socket` property in *BrowserSync* options :

```
var bs, browserSync = require("browser-sync");
...
gulp.task('bs', ['start-node'], () => {
    bs = browserSync.create();
    bs.init({
        proxy: "localhost:8081", // Address of my running local node server
        port: 8082, // dev. ...

        socket: {
            path: "/browser-sync/socket.io",
            clientPath: "/browser-sync",
            namespace: "/browser-sync",
            domain: "dev.ahs502.ir"
        },

        ui: {
            port: 9090, // bs. ...
            weinre: {
                port: 9091 // test. ...
            }
        }
    });
    bs.watch("app/views/*.jade").on("change", bs.reload);
});
```

The next important thing is not to use port `8083` for anything when you are using port `8082` as *browser-sync*'s port. So, I've used port `9090` for *browser-sync*'s **UI** instead of port `8083`.

That's it !

and thank you all.